# sql merge two queries result

Tags: mysql, sql

using xampp mysql
q1:

```
SELECT truckid, count(deliveryid) 
  FROM `delivery` 
 WHERE year(deliverydate)=2019 and month(deliverydate)=1 
 GROUP BY truckid
```

q2:

```
 SELECT truckid,count(deliverid) 
   FROM `delivery2` 
  WHERE YEAR(ddate)=2019 and MONTH(ddate)=1 
  GROUP BY truckid
```

I am trying to get a result of one page with 4 col that will let me compare between them

I already done it last month i think i used left join but i cant seem to get it to work now :(

help .

Comment: If you need them side by side, then you need a `JOIN`; a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to be precise. Unfortunately MySQL does not implement those. You can merge to `LEFT JOIN`, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` & do conditional aggregation :

```
select truckid, 
       sum( tbl = 'delivery' ) as delivery_count,
       sum( tbl = 'delivery2' ) as delivery2_count
from (select truckid, deliveryid, 'delivery' as tbl
      from delivery
      where year(deliverydate) = 2019 and month(deliverydate) = 1
      union all
      select truckid, deliverid, 'delivery2'
      from delivery2
      where YEAR(ddate) = 2019 and MONTH(ddate) = 1
     ) t
group by truckid;
```

Comment: That works too. Interesting it's not the first time you solve it using a totally different approach, compared to mine.

Comment: hmm why is the tables in the select like a col?  truckid, deliverid, 'delivery2' <-- ? geting error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'table = 'delivery' ) as delivery_count,
       sum( table = 'delivery2' ) as de' at line 2 and am not really sure what u did there :P

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a `FULL OUTER JOIN` by `UNION`-ing a `LEFT JOIN` with a `RIGHT JOIN`, as in:

```
with
a (truckid, cnt) as ( -- query #1
  SELECT truckid, count(deliveryid)
  FROM delivery
  WHERE year(deliverydate) = 2019 
    and month(deliverydate) = 1 
  group by truckid
),
b (truckid, cnt) as ( -- query #2
  SELECT truckid, count(deliverid) 
  FROM delivery2
  WHERE YEAR(ddate) = 2019 
    and MONTH(ddate) = 1 
  GROUP BY truckid
)
select -- now the full outer join 
from a.truck_id, a.cnt as a_cnt, b.cnt as b_cnt
left join b on a.truck_id = b.truck_id
union
select 
from b.truck_id, a.cnt as a_cnt, b.cnt as b_cnt
right join b on a.truck_id = b.truck_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
select truckid, max(delivery1) as delivery1, max(delivery2) as delivery2
from ((select truckid, count(*) as delivery1, 0 as delivery2
       from delivery
       where deliverydate >= '2019-01-01' and deliverydate < '2019-01-02'
       group by truckid
      )
      union all
      (select truckid, 0, count(*) as delivery2
       from delivery2
       where deliverydate >= '2019-01-01' and deliverydate < '2019-01-02'
       group by truckid
      )
     ) t
group by truckid;
```

I think this is the most efficient approach.

First, the date ranges allow the use of indexes.

Second, the `group by` on the individual tables is on a smaller sized data.  `GROUP BY` scales worse than linearly, so smaller is better.

The `UNION ALL` is also on smaller data.

And as a convenience, no conditional logic is directly needed.